# Catel InterestedIn is obsolete, use services instead. Any example for the service way?

Tags: catel

The [documentation](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/MVVM+communication+styles) about service is less informative than the other two ways.
If Viewmodel A is to be aware of the property change of Viewmodel B, what's the example code of doing this by service?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out some open source apps written using Catel:

- [CsvTextEditor](https://github.com/WildGums/CsvTextEditor)
- [LogViewer](https://github.com/WildGums/LogViewer)
- [Orchestra](https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra)

Comment: Thanks, I guess the PropertyChanged event does the tricks, although it's not straightforward as InterestedIn.